# Using Homestead with downloaded box file

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I am trying to install laravel/homestead and following the steps described in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead .

In doing that I initially ran into problems while adding a box in "First Step", so I had to download the virtualbox file externally and added the box using that file:

```
$ vagrant box list
There are no installed boxes! Use `vagrant box add` to add some.
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead virtualbox/homestead.box 
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://D:/Code/virtualbox/homestead.box
    box:
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!

$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
Cloning into 'Homestead'...
...
$ cd Homestead ; git checkout v5.4.0
Note: checking out 'v5.4.0'.
$ bash init.sh
Homestead initialized!
```

My trouble is in doing `vagrant up`, it is still trying to download and failing. How can I tell vagrant not to download the box file anymore and use the existing box ?

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to 
    find and install...
    homestead-7: Box Provider: virtualbox
    homestead-7: Box Version: >= 2.0.0
==> homestead-7: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead-7: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
==> homestead-7: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v2.1.0) for provider: 
    virtualbox
    homestead-7: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/2.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
```

I have tried naming my box in first step to homestead-7 , no luck yet. on subsequent executions of `vagrant up`, vagrant claims to resume from prior download , but the progress does not suggest so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

You have installed version 0 of the box `laravel/homestead`. In your version of homestead, it requires to have [version](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/homestead.rb#L18) greater than 2.0.0.

If you want to use your version of the box, you can add a `version` parameter in your json file.

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "ip": "192.168.10.10",
    "memory": 2048,
    "cpus": 1,
    "provider": "virtualbox",
    ...
}
```